# What's the best way to control distribution/usage of proprietary, internal software?

Tags: c#, licensing, security, distribution, proprietary

I was tasked with writing software for my company. As I am now writing a third  program (with many more coming), what's the best way to control the distribution/usage of our software?

The software I'm writing should only be used on our network and shouldn't run elsewhere. We are a small company and don't have the infrastructure set up to see files that have been copied.

Is serial keys the answer? That seems like it would be a pain for the other employees who use the software. Or is there a better, more secure way?

I'm interested to know what ways I can mitigate/prevent usage of our software outside of our company network.

Comment: Set up some secured resource on the internal network that the software has to validate against.  If the resource doesn't exist, the software doesn't run.

Comment: There are several licensing server products available on the market. The costs of such a product is typically lower than the costs of the required server machine, or the costs of the additional working time you would have to invest without such a product. However, even if the software is used currently within the network, expect offline usage as a future requirement.

Comment: Why is the prospect of employees distributing it such a significant threat? Is there a big padlock on the supply closet?